# How do you maximize lift while keeping span as short as possible?

Tags: aerodynamics

This weekend I saw the *Fly Baby* at the Smithsonian Air & Space Museum at the Washington Dulles Airport, and it was at some point the smallest airplane (since surpassed by the *Bumble Bee II*, if I understand correctly). To be able to carry a pilot and lift the plane off the ground in the first place, but still be the smallest airplane, you are mostly limited by wingspan, or more generally, the total width of the airplane.

For the purpose of this question I would like to assume a given airfoil and to exclude modifications to the airfoil itself, i.e. any mechanism that increases lift in pure 2D flow, e.g.  camber, slats, flaps, active blowing of the upper surface etc. I would like to limit the scope to the "3D planform" of the wing(s) - e.g. aspect ratio, sweep, depth, winglets/end plates/..., box wings, number of wings etc. The airplane needs to have a fuselage that holds the pilot and an engine. Otherwise the configuration can be whatever it needs to be. If the configuration for maximizing lift depends on the choice of airfoil, then just assume a suitable airfoil.

Both record-holding planes are biplanes, with the *Bumble Bee* having a relatively large horizontal stabilizer. It also has endplates on the wingtips, reducing lift loss due to the tip vortex.

How can one maximize the lift for a given width?

(I could list all of the ways that come to mind and ask whether and how much they help, but then I'd have "more than one question" and I'm not sure that would be suitable for this format)

Edit: Further clarification: I am asking about maximizing the coefficient of lift of the entire airplane, not about lift itself (which could be maximized by flying faster, to a certain extent). Also, I would like the answer to be valid for low flying speeds (incompressible flow).

Comment: You're right, I meant the plane needs to only carry a single person. From my understanding, the airfoil is the 2D cross-section of the wing, and the wing is 3D, being a simple extrusion of the airfoil in a straight line, or tapered, or swept ... I tried to add some precision to the question. I wanted to exclude the airfoil and all the tricks to maximize lift in 2D (some I've listed in the question) because the scope would be too large.

Comment: I clarified further that I am indeed asking about coefficient of lift of the entire plane (yes, fuselage shape has an effect, but speed and weight don't). I think it is very well answerable, since I am pretty sure I am not the first one to think about this, but I personally lack the understanding of intricate 3D flow around multiple wings, that's why I am asking. E.g. could the lift be improved on the mentioned designs by turning the biplane wing into a box wing (everything else being equal)? Is it maximum for 2 wings, or can one add more?

Comment: The basic design limitations are rather confined, but one must consider the airfoil as a variable in developing that design.  Major controlling factors are wing loading and power. One needs sufficient airspeed to get the lift required for flight.

Comment: Of course, any wing arrangement really (triplanes, box-wings, tandems ...).

Comment: By "narrow wing" do you mean a small *wingspan*?  That is not how most readers will intuitively understand your question.  I'd suggest an edit that employs terms like "span" and "chord" rather than terms like "narrow" and "width".

Comment: Unfortunately, lifting fuselages are not as good as wings for slow flight, although the [albatross](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albatross) does a wonderful job making it as good as it can.  High aspect is the way to go, avoiding wing tip (plates) and [fuselage](https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/aerodynamics/how-interference-drag-affects-your-airplane-performance-and-decreases-performance-speed/) (fairings) interference as much as possible.

Comment: @quietflyer The question title was edited by somebody else in the meantime ... I'll change it back to something more accurate.

Comment: Ever think of trying [this](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/a-4fu-corsair-with-its-wings-folded--328410997810252762/)?

Comment: Some of your parameters are extraneous distractions. Do you want to maximize lift coefficient for a given wingspan/width, or do you want to minimize wingspan for a given useful load(pilot & fuel) and airspeed? These goals are in direct conflict as you cant maximize lift while keeping lift fixed nor minimize wingspan while keeping wingspan fixed.

Comment: A gyrocopter has a extremely high lift coefficient and can be further improved by stacking rotors and adding blades per rotor, unlike a conventional airplane where you run into diminishing returns quickly when the aspect ratio is too low.

Answer (score 4):

The [Chance Vought V-173](https://www.flightmuseum.com/explore/chance-vought-v-173-flying-pancake/) "[flying pancake](https://youtu.be/LfpTDOAfj7Y?t=90)" was designed to provide low speed flight with very low aspect ratio wings. In fact, the entire body is a wing and the twin propellers are arranged to blow their slip stream over that body. It could very nearly hover, so the lift coefficient is extremely high.

[image]

With modern flight control computers the vestigial horizontal tail could be incorporated into the rear fuselage as is done with flying wings. You can see that this has already been done with the center part of the tail. If you were concerned about the width of the props, they could be moved inboard and wing twist altered.

Comment: The flaps at the "center part of the tail" on V-173 are not control surfaces. They serve to reduce the massive ground effect this airplane had on landing. They only moved upwards and were added later when the problem with landing was discovered. The stubby "wings" on either side are just elevons and are entirely in the prop slipstream to allow control at low speed. The props, by the way, rotate outwards to counteract the tip vortex, which significantly increases the effective wingspan. (Or should we call it "bodyspan" here?)

Comment: @Zeus Good info on the tail.

Answer (score 0):

The only significant option you have within the parameters given is to increase the chord. And this has no maximum unless the plane also has a maximum length. but then you increase effective wing area by vertically stacking more wings, again like cord theoretically infinite unless you have a height restriction.

Wingtip devices are effective but rather binary in nature, either you use them or don't, their isn't any real scaling involved other than matching the general size of the wing. They also add weight, which is why they are popular for long haul where fuel is a large fraction of payload but not short haul where the added weight causes more fuel burn than the aerodynamic savings. Many many variables, maybe too many to fully account for with current engineering tools and knowledge, at least for a question like what is "best".

<s>By the way the bumble bee was a terribly unstable short range racing plane.</s> The Bee Gee was the short wing speed record and racing airplane. It was designed to get lift from speed and minimize high speed drag without regard to low speed effectiveness.The Bee Gee was the short wing speed record and racing airplane.

Comment: @quietflyer Don't spam the comments.

Comment: @quietflyer ah yes I was thinking of the GeeBee not BumbleBee I will edit that.

Answer (score -1):

> ... camber, slats, flaps, blowing of the surfaces

Unfortunately, they are some of the best ways of increasing Coefficient of Lift, far better than trying multiple wings, as seen with the Fiesler Fi 156 [Storch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieseler_Fi_156_Storch).

Deep **camber**, undercamber, increasing chord (and, proportionally, thickness) are [helpful](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=dae21-il) in particular, as are endplates.  Another wing or [two](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker_Dr.1) can be added.
Weight should be reduced as much as possible with safe structural strength requirements in mind.

But now you have a very **draggy**, slow aircraft with limited range,
unless you can **retract these** devices and [speed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colomban_Cri-cri) up a little.

> Lift is proportional to V$^2$

If you have *even more power*, and the option to go supersonic, a short **single wing** like [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-104_Starfighter)
or a **lifting body with no wing** at all like [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_Chaser) one would suffice.

It really depends on your fuel budget and available thrust.  Cost conscious subsonic airliners use retractable lifting devices, and even slower speeds are required only because of airspeed limits, runway length, and the quality of the landing gear (especially tires).

Comment: Keep in mind some of these "record setting" aircraft may not be very [safe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starr_Bumble_Bee_II) to fly

Comment: Lift is also proportional to ***S***.

Comment: "... not very safe"  Indeed - don't think about turning in that thing!  Ok, maybe 5 degree AOB...

Comment: The question explicitly says not to alter the basic airfoil. Increased cord implies proportional thickness if the airfoil designation is unchanged.

Comment: @MaxPower actually, the question **specifically says fly slowly**.  If you want to argue how it's been done for 100 years, be my guest.  BTW, the answer does include increasing *chord*, did you see it?

Comment: My reading comprehension is just fine. "I would like to assume a given airfoil and to **exclude** modifications to the airfoil itself, i.e. any mechanism that increases lift in pure 2D flow, e.g. **camber**, slats, flaps, active blowing of the upper surface etc. "

Comment: @MaxPower we read on then about increasing Coefficient of lift, and my second reference to the DAE 21 (and bird wings).  Undercamber is key to increasing Coefficient of Lift.  This is really "mission impossible" as seen in the high stall speeds of current designs. (Notice the "pancake" is blown). Let's move on.

Comment: Coefficients are relative, while the common convention is to use horizontal wing area as the reference it is not the only reference that can be plugged into the equation. The only catch is that like must be compared with like, so a frontal reference area coefficient or width based coefficient[this case] could not be numerically compared to a plan-form area coefficient.

Comment: @MaxPower the Lift Equation takes care of all that.  Unfortunately for the OP, body lift does not work very well at low speeds.

Comment: Do you mean low speed as compared to compressible supersonic flow, or just a change in speed within the incompressible speed regime?

Comment: @MaxPower Within the low Mach "incompressible" range (circa 1918) Gottingen made some really good low speed wings.  V$^2$ has the most powerful effect on lift.  For very slow flight, you are right if not changing the airfoil, *span should increase with chord*, or stack multiwings.  Increasing lift coefficient (with more camber) is also useful.

Comment: Just increasing chord (and reducing weight) would give one something akin to a paraglider with horrible handling in the wind and not as great lifting efficiency.  Large square wings (eagles) are useful in strong thermals (have a look at a clipper square rigger), but lack lifting *efficiency* (have a look at a schooner or an albatross).  The "pancake" works at low speeds because it's blown, and at high speeds because of low drag.